# Receive function call in C

Tags: c, recursion, function-call

Why this recursive function is falling in infinite loop ?   It showing value of Val is not decreasing. What's the logic behind.

```
int Bar(int Val) // value passed is 3
{
    int x=0;
    while (Val>0)
    {
        x=x+Bar(val-1);
    }
    return Val
}
```

Comment: Please provide a correct example. Your code will not compile due to upper case letters, missing braces etc..

Comment: Your recursion terminates properly but on every level of recursion you create an infite loop.

Comment: are `Val` and `val supposed to be the same variables? Or they are different?

Comment: @Gerhardh they are same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the recursion, but the while cycle which never ends.

```
while (val>0) {  
  x=x+bar(val-1);
}
```

In this loop, you never change the value of `val`. So the loop never terminates.

Comment: You mean if there will be 'val-- ' will it be a right choice to terminate?

Comment: @RavirajGardi: yes, it would be a valid choice, at least "formally".

Comment: Also in x=x+bar(**here**)  if we put val-- it's saying abnormal termination. What is reason.

Comment: @RavirajGardi In that case you need to use `--val` to decrement the value before calling the function. Otherweise you will always call with same value and never terminate the recursion. (But the loop will terminate.)

Answer (score 1):

@linuxfan is right.

Maybe you want to do the following:

```
while (val>0) {  
  x=x+bar(--val);
}
```

which both pass the value value decreased by 1 and change the loop variable.

Note another thing: assuming you misspelled `Val` and `val`, if they are the same variable the returned value will be always 0 because loop terminates when `val` is 0 and then returns this value.

Try this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Bar(int val) // value passed is 3
{
    int x=0;
    while (val>0)
    {
        x=x+Bar(--val);
    }
    printf("%d\n", val);
    return val;
}

int main (void)
{
  Bar(3);
  return 0;
}
```